# How to adjust a UILabel placed under UITextView resized with autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I have an objective-c application and I'm using autolayout. I have a tableview, and the cells contains a UIImageView, a UITextView, another UIImageView and one UILabel added. Like:
[image]

I want keep whe cell with the image and label under textView, but when I run my app, the label and the image are on the textView...

I have this functions to apply an adjust to the content of UITextView depending of size and font of the text:

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText: (NSAttributedString*)text andWidth: (CGFloat)width {
    UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:brokenCars[indexPath.row] attributes:attrsDictionary];

    return [self textViewHeightForAttributedText:attrString andWidth:CGRectGetWidth(self.myTable.bounds)-31]+50;


}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     ...
     [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
     ...
    }

//In the UITableViewCell:

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    [self.myText sizeToFit];
    [self.myText layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [self.myText sizeThatFits:(CGSizeMake(self.myText.contentSize.width, FLT_MAX+30))];
    [self.myText setContentSize:size];
}
```

And I have added this constraints:
To left first UIImageView:

[image]

To UITextView:

[image]

To second down UIImageView:

[image]

And to the UILabel:

[image]

What am I doing bad?
How can I move this and hold down the UITextView always?

Thanks!

EDIT 1:
Add this to more crearly. I want get this, always the label and image dwon of textview, but textView extended showing all text:

[image]

I'm showing all text extended but the image and label is on the text like fist picture.

Comment: Can you draw how it should look?

Comment: I have edit and added a draw in storyboard like I want to look. Thanks!

Comment: i can fix this. add this one controller to a demo project and give it via any repo or dropbox. i cannot explain without showing you. i mean in graph i cannot explain very well but i know the solution.

Comment: one more thing i want to confirm. 1) you want the textview to be extended vertically to show its full content and with this you want the label and image should be placed below the textview? 2) you want the label to be resized vertically according to its inside content or you want fixed size of label?

Comment: Yes!! I want 1) and I don't want resized the UILabel, only want show this below the textView. Thanks!!

Comment: Need you my uploaded example project xcode? Or can you upload an example? I didn't understand your last anwer sorry. Thanks!!